# Why doesn't JavaScript's .call function work with object literals?

Tags: javascript, call, object-literal

Using the Function.Prototype.call example on the Mozilla Dev Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Why doesn't the example work when passing in an object literal instead of an argument array? The example should assign name and price to the Product prototype and return a Food and Toy object with the corresponding name and price fields, but the results come back undefined.

```
function Product(data) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.price = data.price;

    if (price < 0)
         throw RangeError('Cannot create product "' + name + '" with a negative      price');
    return this;
}

function Food(data) {
    Product.call(this,data);
    this.category = 'food';
}
    Food.prototype = new Product();

function Toy(data) {
    Product.call(this,data);
    this.category = 'toy';
}
    Toy.prototype = new Product();

var cheese = new Food({ name: 'feta', price: 5 });
var fun = new Toy({ name: 'robot', price: 40 });

console.log(cheese);
console.log(fun);
```

In chrome I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' error after the call function has passed reference to the Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
Food.prototype = new Product();
// ...
Toy.prototype = new Product();
```

You're calling `Product` without passing an argument. You should use `Object.create` instead.

```
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
// ...
Toy.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

This lets you make an object that inherits from another object *(`Product.prototype` in this case)*, without having to invoke a constructor function.

---

Also, this:

```
if (price < 0)
```

should be this:

```
if (this.price < 0)
```

Comment: This resolves the invocation issue, but once the prototype receives the object literal it is undefined. This is the result: Food {name: undefined, price: undefined, category: "food"} Toy {name: undefined, price: undefined, category: "toy"}

Comment: @JuiceByCharly: It's not `undefined`. There's some other issue that's not represented in your question. Given the code you provided, it works fine when the fixes are applied. http://jsfiddle.net/2Mj3k/